# Core-data one to many relationship loses his relationship after fetching new objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, nsfetchrequest

I've asked this question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374504/core-data-relationship-lost-after-fetching-more-objects-into-the-entities). But i'm opening a new one because I have some other insights now. First of all this is how my `core data model` looks like.

[image]

Now when I fetch my first `appointments` into my model. Everything works oké. But the problem comes when I load up new appointments. Then the previous appointments location relation goes to `NULL`. The strange things is that the `location relationship` only works with the appointments that are last loaded in.

[image]

I'm using `restkit` for mapping my `JSON` into my `core-data model`. And this is how I made the relationship.

```
 [locationMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"appointments" toKeyPath:@"appointments" withMapping:appointmentMapping]];
```

Can anybody help me with this  problem ?

Comment: Just a suggestion, but debugging via SQLite is really painful. You might find [PonyDebugger](https://github.com/square/PonyDebugger#core-data-browser) useful.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but the original JSON deserializer and straight core data methods are really simple, so why not try without RestKit?

Comment: Because I need to save the objects that I get back from my JSON into Core data, And restkit does this pretty well I think.

Comment: You added a bounty to your other question - that is the correct thing to do and you should add new information to that question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your model is horrible (no offense). You should create LabelData, Data and VerplichtData entities. These should have to-one relationships to Location / Appointment. Location and Appointment  should have to-many relationships to LabelData, Data and VerplichtData.

You should probably follow Mundis advice and not use rest kit, it will probably make debugging lots easier. [Apple has a pretty decent strategy for importing data in a smart way](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html) (i.e. fast and without duplication). Here a copy-paste from the docs in case the link dies:

*Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently
A common technique when importing data is to follow a "find-or-create" pattern, where you set up some data from which to create a managed object, determine whether the managed object already exists, and create it if it does not.
There are many situations where you may need to find existing objects (objects already saved in a store) for a set of discrete input values. A simple solution is to create a loop, then for each value in turn execute a fetch to determine whether there is a matching persisted object and so on. This pattern does not scale well. If you profile your application with this pattern, you typically find the fetch to be one of the more expensive operations in the loop (compared to just iterating over a collection of items). Even worse, this pattern turns an O(n) problem into an O(n^2) problem.
It is much more efficient—when possible—to create all the managed objects in a single pass, and then fix up any relationships in a second pass. For example, if you import data that you know does not contain any duplicates (say because your initial data set is empty), you can just create managed objects to represent your data and not do any searches at all. Or if you import "flat" data with no relationships, you can create managed objects for the entire set and weed out (delete) any duplicates before save using a single large IN predicate.
If you do need to follow a find-or-create pattern—say because you're importing heterogeneous data where relationship information is mixed in with attribute information—you can optimize how you find existing objects by reducing to a minimum the number of fetches you execute. How to accomplish this depends on the amount of reference data you have to work with. If you are importing 100 potential new objects, and only have 2000 in your database, fetching all of the existing and caching them may not represent a significant penalty (especially if you have to perform the operation more than once). However, if you have 100,000 items in your database, the memory pressure of keeping those cached may be prohibitive.
You can use a combination of an IN predicate and sorting to reduce your use of Core Data to a single fetch request. Suppose, for example, you want to take a list of employee IDs (as strings) and create Employee records for all those not already in the database. Consider this code, where Employee is an entity with a name attribute, and listOfIDsAsString is the list of IDs for which you want to add objects if they do not already exist in a store.
First, separate and sort the IDs (strings) of interest.*

```
// get the names to parse in sorted order
NSArray *employeeIDs = [[listOfIDsAsString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]
    sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
Next, create a predicate using IN with the array of name strings, and a sort descriptor which ensures the results are returned with the same sorting as the array of name strings. (The IN is equivalent to an SQL IN operation, where the left-hand side must appear in the collection specified by the right-hand side.)

// Create the fetch request to get all Employees matching the IDs.
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:
    [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:aMOC]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(employeeID IN %@)", employeeIDs]];

// make sure the results are sorted as well
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:
    @[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"employeeID" ascending:YES]]];
Finally, execute the fetch.

NSError *error;
NSArray *employeesMatchingNames = [aMOC executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
You end up with two sorted arrays—one with the employee IDs passed into the fetch request, and one with the managed objects that matched them. To process them, you walk the sorted lists following these steps:

Get the next ID and Employee. If the ID doesn't match the Employee ID, create a new     Employee for that ID.
Get the next Employee: if the IDs match, move to the next ID and Employee.
Regardless of how many IDs you pass in, you only execute a single fetch, and the rest is just walking the result set.
```

*The listing below shows the complete code for the example in the previous section.*

```
// Get the names to parse in sorted order.
NSArray *employeeIDs = [[listOfIDsAsString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]
    sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];

// create the fetch request to get all Employees matching the IDs
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:
    [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:aMOC]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(employeeID IN %@)",     employeeIDs]];

// Make sure the results are sorted as well.
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:
@[ [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"employeeID" ascending:YES] ]];
// Execute the fetch.
NSError *error;
NSArray *employeesMatchingNames = [aMOC executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```